# Authenticating Cookies with PHP and Curl

Tags: php, api, authentication, curl

I am writing code against the [Space-Track API](https://www.space-track.org/documentation), and the curl request is failing to authenticate. My code is as follows:

```
$curl = curl_init();

$url = "https://www.space-track.org/basicspacedata/query/class/tle/EPOCH/%3C1969-12-18/NORAD_CAT_ID/4/orderby/EPOCH%20desc/limit/1/format/3le/metadata/true";

$c = curl_init('https://www.space-track.org/auth/login?identity=XXX&password="XXX"');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
$page = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

$c = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
$page = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

echo $page;
```

The response received is: "You must be logged in to complete this action"

The authentication is apparently successful, however, as the cookies.txt file is filled with an authentication message.

I have read a number of tutorials on curl authentication, and I have also tried other users' implementations of the space-track API in php ([eg](https://github.com/sodonnell/spacetrack)) but have not managed to make these work with my request:

```
https://www.space-track.org/basicspacedata/query/class/tle/EPOCH/%3C1969-12-18/NORAD_CAT_ID/4/orderby/EPOCH%20desc/limit/1/format/3le/metadata/true
```

The request works in the browser (direct access) when authenticated and via terminal, but not when run in the script. Direct browser access returns this correct response:

```
0 EXPLORER 1
1 00004U 58001  A 69351.29911760  .00162519 +00000-0 +00000-0 0  9991
2 00004 033.1571 316.5155 0244636 013.0841 347.6023 15.32472396567852
```

Any assistance in correctly authenticating and receiving this response via PHP gratefully received.